# Python Pandas: choosing maximum length of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of 3 people, and their DNA sequences. The full genome of each person comprises of two genes (strings): gene1 and gene2 (i.e. `full_genome = gene1+gene2`), and sometimes, there are erroneous duplicate entries.

The table is currently structured as:

```
row_num | name   | gene_name | dna_sequence
--------|--------|-----------|--------------
1       | sarah  | gene 1    | aaaaaaaaaa
2       | sarah  | gene 2    | gggggggggg
3       | charles| gene 1    | aaaattttt
4       | charles| gene 2    | ggggggtttt
5       | eric   | gene 1    | aaa
6       | eric   | gene 2    | cccccccccc
7       | eric   | gene 1    | aaaaa
8       | eric   | gene 2    | cccc
9       | eric   | gene 1    | a
10      | eric   | gene 2    | c
```

Note the duplicate entries for Eric in rows 5 to 10. Out of all these, I want to just choose the longest total sequence (i.e. `argmax(len(gene1)+len(gene2))`), rows 5 and 6. I'd also like to pivot the table to eventually end up with:

```
name   | gene1      | gene2 
-------|------------|-----------
sarah  | aaaaaaaaaa | gggggggggg
charles| aaaattttt  | ggggggtttt
eric   | aaaaaaaaaa | cccccccccc
```

Note that the genes always come in pairs: each data source submits their data as one file, and the table was formed by reading in file by file. So in Eric's case, the total gene lengths are as follows:

- Rows 5 & 6: 3 + 10 = 13
- Rows 7 & 8: 5 + 4 = 9
- Rows 9 & 10: 1 + 1 = 2

Based on longest total gene length, I'd keep rows 5 and 6, and discard the rest.

I've tried pivot(), transpose(), and suchlike, but it's rather become a chicken-and-egg thing: I can't pivot the table into the desired form because of duplicate entries, but I can't get measure the total lengths either because it's not easy to tell which duplicate entry came from where.

I'm currently trying to add a `duplicate_index` column, so that I can distinguish between duplicates:

```
row_num | name   | gene_name | dna_sequence | dupe_index
--------|--------|-----------|--------------|------------
1       | sarah  | gene 1    | aaaaaaaaaa   | 0
2       | sarah  | gene 2    | gggggggggg   | 0
3       | charles| gene 1    | aaaattttt    | 0
4       | charles| gene 2    | ggggggtttt   | 0
5       | eric   | gene 1    | aaa          | 0
6       | eric   | gene 2    | cccccccccc   | 0
7       | eric   | gene 1    | aaaaa        | 1
8       | eric   | gene 2    | cccc         | 1
9       | eric   | gene 1    | a            | 2
10      | eric   | gene 2    | c            | 2
```

Comment: Do these entries always come in pairs?  Is it possible you might have (simplifying) "a", "cccc" followed by "aa", "cc", and you'd want the "a", "cccc" pair, because it has total length 5?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly correct. Edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***attempt 1***

```
df.loc[
    df.dna_sequence.str.len().groupby([df.name, df.gene_name]).idxmax()
].set_index(['name', 'gene_name']).dna_sequence.unstack()

gene_name      gene 1      gene 2
name                             
charles     aaaattttt  ggggggtttt
eric            aaaaa  cccccccccc
sarah      aaaaaaaaaa  gggggggggg
```

Comment: Just this worked fine, actually:
df.loc[df.dna_sequence.str.len().groupby([df.name, df.gene_name]).idxmax()].set_index(['name', 'gene_name'])